# Excel - checkbox select all in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm new to Visual Basic. I tried to

```
Sub SelectAll_Click()
'Update 20150309
Dim xCheckBox As CheckBox
For Each xCheckBox In Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If xCheckBox.Name <> Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then
        xCheckBox.Value = Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I have named my master checkbox as "Select All". I have trouble in Module Window where pops out Error 1004. If anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What result were you expecting? Do you know which line creates the error? Try running through the code manually by pressing F8, line by line, to see where the error appears.

Comment: I want to check/uncheck all checkboxes by clicking only one checkbox - master checkbox. Error appears at 4th line (which starts from "if xCheckBox.Name <> ..."

Comment: The most probable reason is that there is no checkbox called "Check Box 1" in the active worksheet, so this expression `Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1")` return `Nothing`. Then you try to get its `Name` property - but trying to get a property from `Nothing` always return 1004 error.

Comment: I just ran your macro and it works for me, exactly as written. Are you sure you have a checkbox with the name "Check Box 1"? Maybe you renamed it and that checkbox no longer exists.

Comment: Ok thank you, now I know where I made mistake. But still I don't know where should I change name of my checkbox for "Check Box 1"...

Comment: You can change the name of your checkbox if you want, but then in the code above, where it refers to "Check Box 1", you need to make it explicitly state the new name of your checkbox.

Comment: By default, Check Boxes are called `CheckBox1` (no spaces). You might want to give that a go.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, it works :-)